# Keeping a process alive and tracking the latest pid

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pid

I'm trying to restart a process on crash and the following script seems to work out:

```
until $@; do
  echo "Process crashed with exit code $?. Respawning..." >&2
  sleep 5
done
```

However I would like to track the pid of the latest process so that I can gracefully kill it for cleanup purposes if the above script is terminated. I've tried various things including `until [$@ & PID=$!];` but util needs the initial, long running command. How can I set the `$PID` variable as the latest process pid?

Comment: why can't use watch? if you want to track the pid id?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the PID of the process that you are restarting, you should:

```
/command/to/start/process &
PID=$!
```

Note the `&` at the end of the command, otherwise the `PID=$!` will be executed only after the above line has exited (or daemonized itself) and the `$!` variable will be empty,